# can't receive notification in ios : sending FcmTokenRefreshed with no listeners registered

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-fcm

i send notification with fire-base , in ios app i have this error : 
sending FcmTokenRefreshed with no listeners registered
if app opened receive notification but when app closed not receive and show error .
excuse me for bad English!

"react": "16.4.1"

"react-native": "0.55.4"

"react-native-fcm": "^16.2.4",

"xcode 10.1"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put this lines in your

FILE : AppDelegate.m :

1 )

```
import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"  
import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
```

2 ) add this line to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

3 )  add methods

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

 (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                       fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

  (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i use react-native-fcm your code for react-native-firebase